# Duplicate underlaying WCF calls

Tags: performance, wcf, soap, task-parallel-library

I have WCF client on my WPF app. WCF client is generated with asynchronous operations.

I am doing parallel calls with awaiting to Tasks.

I noticed some delay on data getting and when sniffed traffic with Microsoft Message Analyzer, noticed, that for some calls I did 2 request were sent with about 500ms interval but got one response.

In my app I have only one call.

Question is why 2 underlying calls were sent by WCF client?

P.S. I checked by hosting service under IIS and IIS express. Same result on both cases.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just calling the operation twice? Maybe your client is receiving a response from the first call but timing out waiting for the second call?

Comment: @TomRedfern there is for sure 1 call.

Comment: Does your service log two calls?

Comment: What protocol/binding are you using? MS Message Analyzer seems to be for low level (IP/Network) layer messaging. There may not be a one to one mapping from messages sent vs number of calls made.

Comment: That is meaningless. Your service is the ultimate arbiter of how many logical service calls were made, not network level analysis.

Comment: I am using SOAP with basicHttpBinding

Comment: With MS Message Analyzer I see 2 service calls with same arguments (but app did 1 call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is not with your client or service, but with your analysis tooling.

Microsoft Message Analyzer is designed for low level network monitoring.

Higher level protocols such as SOAP will almost certainly utilise more than one network message per *logical* call.

WCF supports lower-level protocols such as [UDP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751494(v=vs.110).aspx), where the number of messages on the network may bear more resemblance to the number of service calls you make, but this is buy no means garanteed.

As such, the service itself is the ultimate arbiter of how many logical service calls it has received.

If you do need to analyse the underlying traffic, you could also look at [WCF Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx), which will group network calls together into "conversations", that resolve to a single instance of a client-service request/response pair.

Comment: I will try WCF Tracing.

Comment: I enabled logging of WCF on client side and server side. Calls were queued at the same time, but processed sequentially on UI side.

Comment: @SamvelSiradeghyan so what conclusions can you draw from that? Does this confirm your original analysis?

Comment: Yes, this was what I was hoping to see.